# Posición de una dato en una lista (Python)

Tags: python

Pregunta, si tengo un elemento que pertenecía a una lista y quiero saber en que posición de la lista estaba. Habrá un comando para eso en Python?

Dejo ejemplo de lo que creo

```
a=[s,f,g] a[0]=s s->
```

Comment: `tulista.index('valorbuscado')` retornará la posición

Comment: Como comenta Dev. Joel el método [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) es lo que buscas. Ten en cuenta dos cosas: lanza un error de tipo `ValueError` si el elemento no se encuentra en la lista y que si hay elementos repetidos solo retorna el índice del primero encontrado (el que tiene el índice más bajo). Si necesitas encontrar los índices de todos los elementos iguales o manejar el error debes crear tu propio método. Saludos.

Answer (score 6):

> list.index(x)

retorna el indice donde aparece X, dentro del `list`

```
>>> a=["s","f","g"]
>>> a
['s', 'f', 'g']
>>> a[0]
's'
>>> a.index('s')
0
>>> a[a.index('s')]
's'
>>> a.index('z')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    a.index('z')
ValueError: 'z' is not in list
```

si deseas encontrar los indices de todas la veces que el elemento se encuentra en la lista te serviría una:

> List Comprehensions

algo así:

```
>>> a=["s","f","g","s","f","g","s","f","g"]
>>> a
['s', 'f', 'g', 's', 'f', 'g', 's', 'f', 'g']
>>> m=[i for i,x in enumerate(a) if x=='s']
>>> m
[0, 3, 6]
```

Mas información sobre `List` y `List Comprehensions` otras estructuras en Python:
[Documentacion Python Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)